# I want to filter Firebase data and display only users filtered by email on a recyclerview on kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have this function on my RecyclerViewActivity, which fetch all data in Firebase Storage

```
  private fun fetchData() {
       FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users")
           .get()
           .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
               for (document in documents){
                   val user = documents.toObjects(User::class.java)
                   // I want to display only users with a determinate email
                   rvUsers.adapter = UserAdapter(this, user)
               }
           }
           .addOnFailureListener {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Error RecyclerViewActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }
   }
}
```

Here is my User class

````
data class User ( var email: String = "",
                  var uid: String = "",
                  var restaurant: String = "",
                  var rating: String = "",
                  var imageUrl: String = ""
                )```
I would like to display only some users on the recyclerview, those are users filtered by email, but I don't know how to do it. Is was triying something like this ```user.equals(email)``` but dind't work. If anyone could help me please
````

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact users you want to filter, and which is the exact criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to answer your question:

1. If you already have your filter before you do any fetch, I heavily suggest making a query just fetching the data you need. No need to get all the collection.
2. If you are going to filter your collection once you get all the data, then I suggest storing your data somewhere in your application, then if you don't have any filter, pass the whole collection to the RV, otherwise, pass the filtered list.

Please, let me know exactly what do you want to do to provide more information.

Comment: I know I can filter before or after getting the data, but I don't know which is the code which will enable me to filter by email. As I said before, I know it could be something like: ```if (user.equals(email)) {
                        rvUsers.adapter = UserAdapter(this, user)
                    }``` The problem is that I don't know how to filter the val user.

Comment: I was trying this: user.filter ```{ it.email.toString() == email }``` But it doesn't work

Comment: I believe this [post](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/implem-search-in-recyclerview-5bc18b547f4f) can help a lot more than I can. Btw, you could map over your users list and then pass that list to the adapter.

Comment: Yeah, the post solved my problem, thank you :D